# how to fix: found a substring in string

Tags: javascript, arrays, swift, string

i have this problem

strArr is ["aaabaaddae", "aed"] then the smallest substring of N that contains the characters a, e, and d is "dae" located at the end of the string. So for this example your program should return the string dae

strArr is ["aabdccdbcacd", "aad"] then the smallest substring of N that contains all of the characters in K is "aabd" which is located at the beginning of the string. Both parameters will be strings ranging in length from 2 to 50 characters and all of K's characters will exist somewhere in the string N. Both strings will only contains lowercase alphabetic characters.

i used js but now i am trying to use swift

Input:["ahffaksfajeeubsne", "jefaa"]
Output:"aksfaje"

this works with js

```
function MinWindowSubstring(strArr){
  var min = null;
  var n = strArr[0];
  var k = strArr[1];
  for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j <= n.length; j++) {
      var sub = n.slice(i, j);
      if(checkK(sub, k)){
        if (min === null || sub.length < min.length){
          min = sub;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return min;
}

function checkK(sub, k){
  var h = k.split('');
  for (var i = 0; i < sub.length; i++) {
    var char = sub[i];
    var index = h.indexOf(char);
    if(index > -1){
      h.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
  if(h.length === 0){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}


console.log(MinWindowSubstring(["aabdccdbcacd", "aad"])); // aabd
console.log(MinWindowSubstring(["ahffaksfajeeubsne", "jefaa"])); // aksfaje
```

this is my code with swift

```
func indexChar(str:String, char: Character) -> Int
{
    let index = str.firstIndex(of: char)
    if index?.encodedOffset != nil
    {
        return (index?.encodedOffset)!
    }
    else
    {
        return 0
    }
}

var arrStr = ["ahffaksfajeeubsne", "jefaa"]
var str1 = arrStr[0]
var str2 = arrStr[1]
var arrIndex = [Int]()
for letra in str2
{
    var index =  indexChar(str: str1, char: letra)
    arrIndex.append(index)
}

print(String(Array(str1)[arrIndex.min()!...arrIndex.max()!]))
```

with js

Input:["ahffaksfajeeubsne", "jefaa"]
Output:"aksfaje"

with swift
input ["ahffaksfajeeubsne", "jefaa"]
output ahffaksfaje

Comment: Your Swift code can return a substring of N which includes all characters in K, but the substring may not be minimum. Why don't you simply convert the JS code into Swift?

Comment: Your examples are inconsistent. Either you are looking for a **consecutive** substring then the first example is `aa` and the second is `aksfaje` or you are looking for a substring which contains all characters then the first example is `aabd` and the second `ahffaksfaje`. The first two `a`s in the second example are the two `a`s in the character array and the third `a` is a *random* character.